# Get all Mathematica fonts into StackExchange

Tags: feature-request

Mathematica has a bunch of custom fonts which define things like `\[Distributed]`. These can be linked displayed on the web by linking against the set of these fonts stored on Wolfram's servers at https://reference.wolfram.com/2013/css/fonts.css (one issue is that WRI didn't set these up in a way that browsers tend to be happy loading them so I have a copy at https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/tutorial/theme/css/common.css which works better)

Doing that we can do things like

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/tutorial/theme/css/common.css">
</head>
<style> 
 .special-char { font-family: "Mathematica" }
</style>
<p> <span class='special-char'>&#63264;</span> </p>
```

And get that  to show up as it should (it's `\[Wolf]` in Mathematica or `&#63264;` in HTML).

You can see that snippet in action [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/sample-char.html) I make use of this for real [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/tutorial/using-mathematica/basics/types.html)

Now my question is: can we get this to work on StackExchange? halirutan's help-bar can turn these ugly long names into unicode, so with a bit of CSS work and we could get these fonts to display properly too.

I understand if this is too much work. I think it'd just be nice.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there would be licensing issues on using these fonts...

Comment: @kirma I thought about that but figured it's such a minor thing Wolfram wouldn't put weird licensing restrictions on them. But also it's Wolfram so who knows :/ That'd be disappointing.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure we'll need to ask permission from WRI first for using these. I don't believe you were around at the time, but we did get into a spot of trouble with the site logo back when we were about to go out of beta, so I don't expect anything smooth from asking them for the font/CSS.